# How to encrypt/decrypt WAV Audio files in Java?

Tags: java, spring-boot, encryption

I am trying to encrypt WAV Audio files and then decrypt them upon requests.
Here is my encrypt function:

```
public void encrypt(File file) throws InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey);
        byte[] initializationVector = cipher.getIV();
        try (FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file.getAbsolutePath()+".enc");
             CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(fileOutputStream, cipher)) {
            fileOutputStream.write(initializationVector);
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath());
            byte[] bytes = fileInputStream.readAllBytes();
            cipherOutputStream.write(bytes);
        }
    }
```

and here is my decrypt function:

```
public void decrypt(File file) throws InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, InvalidKeyException, IOException {
        try (FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getAbsolutePath())) {
            byte[] fileInitializationVector = new byte[16];
            fileInputStream.read(fileInitializationVector);
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(fileInitializationVector));
            try (
                    CipherInputStream cipherInputStream = new CipherInputStream(fileInputStream, cipher);
            ) {
                byte[] decryptedBytes = cipherInputStream.readAllBytes();
                String decryptedString = new String(decryptedBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                BufferedWriter bwr = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File("testout.wav")));
                bwr.write(decryptedString);
            }
        }
    }
```

with text files its working perfectly addressing all new lines, spaces and different charsets/languages inside a text file. But, when i try to use it with .WAV audio files the WAV files are not being played in any player. Some players even suggested that those WAV files are empty (after decryption).
Although the file size is not 0 and there are bytes written inside.
Two thing i noticed are:

1. the codecs are gone from the metadata of the file.
   here is the to be encrypted test wav file properties:

[image: original test file]

and here it is after it was decrypted:

[image: decrypted test file]

2. size of the files are different, original filesize is : 113KBs and decrypted is: 180KBs

Its critical to maintain integrity of the files (this is why i am using encryption in the first place).

Comment: Why do you use a writer in the decrypt, you use correctly binary files in the encrypt, do the same, never use a String to store binary data. Also it's not necessary to use readAllBytes, it loads all your file in the memory.

Comment: @pdem could you write an example, please?